# AngularJS and Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, angularjs

I'm building a site that will run on codeigniter and one of the main features of the site will be an angularjs application. I've tried loading this application through a controller say... Sell. My sell controller loads a view that has my angular setup in it. I ran into a few problems, I'm guessing mostly with the routing...

1. If I go to myurl.com/sell the angular app appears to initialize but it doesn't add /#/ to the url therefor my routes in my app don't work.
2. I can physically type in /sell/#/ and it works, which is good, but it should be automatic.
3. I can turn on html5mode, and that works perfectly fine but I'm guessing it wouldn't work on non HTML5 browsers

I'm suspecting that there's interference with CI's routing logic and AngularJs but it's really odd it's not automatically adding the #.

**Option 2 I tried...**

Another solution would be to move the angular app folder to the directory root but it would be illogical to have a separate set of views, (header, footer includes etc.) for the ang.js app and for the rest of the codeigniter build. I was also wondering if it's possible to extend CI to a root folder so I can load views from the ang.js framework.